# Classic ASP Error Page Not Working IIS 7.5

Tags: asp-classic

I use Classic ASP on IIS7.5 at Windows Server 2008 R2. I have a problem. I have a custom 404 page. And redirect all 404 errors to default.asp. That is work on the web but it's not working on local ! My web.config's setting under the document. Can you help me please about this situation.

```
<customErrors mode="On">
   <error statusCode="404" redirect="/default.asp" />
</customErrors> 

    <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly">
        <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/Default.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        <error statusCode="500" subStatusCode="100" path="/e/Default.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
```

Comment: You wish to redirect all 404s and 500s to a custom page, right? What occurs instead of the expected behaviour when you attempt to test this?

Comment: I test this this is work real but it isn't local iis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

httpErrors errorMode is DetailedLocalOnly So That is work at web bu not work local. I set errorMode = custom and it's work

http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors